# Prevent RXTX from printing version info

Tags: java, serial-port, rxtx

I am using RXTX 2.1-7 on windows, and I have one issue. Whenever I run a program using the RXTX library, the following generic versioning info gets printed:

*Stable Library*

=========================================

Native lib Version = RXTX-2.1-7
Java lib Version   = RXTX-2.1-7

This is fine to help debugging, but I would like to disable this printing now that I have the program set up properly. How do I prevent this print?

Answer (score 5):

You can disable it by passing the system property -Dgnu.io.rxtx.NoVersionOutput=true, i.e. java -Dgnu.io.rxtx.NoVersionOutput=true yourclass.

Answer (score 0):

DZone JavaLobby has an article titled *[How to Capture System.err and System.out](http://java.dzone.com/articles/how-capture-systemerr-and)* which can help you capture the output.